# How do i make a specific component or set of components re-run if they fail in SSIS

Tags: for-loop, ssis, onerror

Im developing a datawarehouse and all of the things that support and come with it. Recently ran into a problem where my SSIS project, made to update and insert data from a database i have into the datawarehouse, fails. The structure of the SSIS project right now is:

- 5 data flow tasks to update de datawarehouse dimensions and insert
  new records from the database if there are any
- 3 fact tables : 3 sql
  tasks used to delete the current day records from the fact tables if
  the projects get ran more than once a day

Going back to the issue, my data flow taks for the dimensions usually fail once or twice due to "non specified errors".

I would like to know if it is possible for me to make the dimensions components get re-run if any of them fail. I assume it is possible using a for-loop but haven't been able to make it work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Logically we don't truncate data from fact tables how can you explain this?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You said 3 sql tasks used to delete the current day records from the fact tables if the projects get ran more than once a day.
Usually we operate only INSERT in the fact tables

Comment: Im aware of it. Im using those 3 sql tasks only due to the fact that the ssis project is still in development and since im running it manually i may need to run it more than once a day and to prevent duplicated data on it i established those SQL query tasks. Apreciate the comment but im looking for help in the regards of the foor loop because i just cant seem to get it right for some reason. Created 3 variables, count, increment and another one so i can verify if the the loop has error or not but it is not working stil.

Comment: Im using the For loop with all the dimensions inside it and since i have ran into the "non specified erro" on them i thought the loop would solve my problem, because usually just re-running the project works fine. I just cant get the loop to only activate when one of the dimensions inside it has an error and thats my goal

Comment: I already provided an answer please check it

Answer (score 0):

Create a couple of variables that you'll need to control the looping, such as `@RetryCount` (to hold the current retry number) and `@MaxRetries` (to define how many times you want to try re-running a failed task).

Then, try to rap the Data Flow Tasks that needs to be re-run inside a For Loop Container. Configure the loop's evaluation expression to check if `@RetryCount` is less than or equal to `@MaxRetries`.

Within the For Loop Container, you can set up expressions that will either increment the `@RetryCount` if a failure occurs or exit the loop if a success occurs. Use the "Expression and Constraint" precedence constraint to achieve this.

In the "For Loop Editor," configure the following expressions:

```
 - InitExpression: `@RetryCount = 0`
 - EvalExpression: `@RetryCount <= @MaxRetries`
 - AssignExpression: `@RetryCount = @RetryCount + 1`
```

To configure the Failure and Success Flow, after connecting the Data Flow Task to the next task with an "Expression and Constraint" precedence constraint use the following expressions like `@RetryCount <= @MaxRetries` to continue the loop on failure, or `@RetryCount > @MaxRetries` to exit on success.

Comment: I will edit the post with some screenshots of what i have done, because im pretty sure i have already made the steps u adviced me too! Although the loop doesnt stop on sucess and it always trys to re-run itself until it fails or achieves the maxtries

Comment: Yes please. And attach your expressions

Comment: Those are the general loop settings and configurations. Also was trying to use event handlers ("onError") with a C# script that updated the ErrorOcurred value to "True" if there was actually an error within the loop. Now that i think of it would make sense the issue is in the event handlers part because i strongly believe the loop is alright

Comment: If it isn´t to much to ask is there any way i can contact you in a more personal way? Im running short on time to get this done and would trully apreciate the help. Already do apreciate the time u investing now!

Comment: https://teams.live.com/l/invite/FEAk1uOYJcCPgl1awE